# Can I exclude a particular file from a GET request while using angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, api, get

I am super new to angular and am doing a project to try and get more familiar with it.

I am using a pokemon API and I am attempting to have sprites match up with the name. The API has different groupings all using a numbering system to identify a particular pokemon. However, there are some numbers that do not match up such as the sprites and the names. 1 for the name is the same as 1 and 2 for the sprites, which makes everything off by 1 once you get to name 2.

At the moment the sprites are always one off because **/sprite/1 is a duplicate of **/sprite/2. 
My question is there any way to exclude **/sprite/1 from being an option?

```
function fetch (){

        $http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" +$scope.search)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log("Data:", data.name)
            $scope.details = data;
    });

    $http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/sprite/" +$scope.search)
    .success(function(data){
      console.log("data:", data.image)
      $scope.sprite = data;
    })
}
```

At the moment with this call I do get a name and a sprite, but they do not match (due to sprite being off by one). Would greatly appreciate any help or advice! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to account for offsets like this in code you'll just find other discrepancies later; use the sprites value in the JSON return to get the correct URLs without guessing. This was taken from $scope.search value 1 (apparently Bulbasaur):

```
"sprites": [
  {"name": "bulbasaur", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/sprite/2/"}, 
  {"name": "bulbasaur", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/sprite/1/"}
]
```

Comment: Oh for sure, but the issue is that that api/v1/pokemon/2 (used for the name) does not match api/v1/sprite/2. 
sprite/1 and sprite/2 are the only repeating sprites. Which is where I'm off by 1

Comment: Yep, understood. What I'm saying, though, is that if you look at the JSON output from api/v1/pokemon/2, you'll see the following:

    "sprites": [{"name": "ivysaur", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/sprite/3/"}]

You need to grab the 'sprites' value from the 'data' parameter you're getting back in your original $http.get(...) in order to get the correct URI for the sprites for any given entry.

Comment: Would a good way to target this be data.sprites[$scope.search.resource_uri])?

Comment: I would say either looping over data.sprites and getting whatever's there (or just the first, if you only need one) is the way to go. But that depends on how you're presenting/using the sprites. I don't know what's in $scope.search.resource_uri, but that shouldn't matter in the context of looking at the sprite list inside of the returned data; it's just a list/array you can iterate over and do whatever you need to with.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll have to figure out how to do that then. 
The sprites (along with name and description) are being displayed when a user types in a particular number(1-778). I have all three displaying, but none matching. Going to have to figure out how to loop through and get the matching ones.

Comment: Try console.log(data.sprites) from inside your .success(...) function. I think you'll see what I mean, and that's where you should be able to get your consistently correct URLs.

Comment: Thanks kungphu, you've been very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm also new to Angular, this is the kind of thing I've been working through for the last couple weeks at work. If this ends up solving your problem, please do mark it as accepted; if not, let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: For sure, I'll be working on this all morning, so if I run into any problems, I'll be sure to come back here!

Comment: Hey, just got the sprites to match up! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! Currently trying to get my 'search' to search using names instead of the number (example pokemon/1). Will probably have to figure out how to use factories somehow.

Comment: Sure thing, glad it helped! I think looking past the particulars of angular into how the web service works and what endpoints it exposes is likely to be enlightening as far as your search needs. Regardless, good luck!